# Is there a way of using multiple prioritized paths to have the pug files?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So, if my project has the views path organized as bellow:

```
views/
  client-1/
  client-2/
  default/
  ...
```

Is there a way of forcing the Pug to look into the folder of the *client* first, and if the file does'nt exists, then looking into the *default*? And making the same with the includes and extends?

Examples:

client1/list.pug:

```
extend includes/header
  block content
    div.bold-as-fck 'Hello Client type one!'
```

default/header.pug:

```
html
  body
    block content
```

default/list.pug:

```
extend includes/header
  block content
    div.not-as-bold 'Hello Client generic type!'
```

So, I would like the code to:

1. when I say `res.render('list')` to check the folder of the current client to see if it has the `list.pug`, if it has it uses, if doesn't, then uses the `default/list.pug` one.
2. to use the same rule above for the `includes` and `extends`.

Is this possible?

Please, have in mind that the html structure of the 'clients' changes a lot, not only a simple css class as I used on the example above.

---

Thinking here, a good solution, would be replacing the following:

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

by the following:

```
app.set('views', [path.join(CLIENT_PATH, '/views'), './views']);
```

Where the order of the items inside the array would set the priority order of the paths to scan for the pug file, would be amazing... But, is already there exists a simular or different solution for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of this sort of behaviour being available in Express. This could, however, be achieved by writing a function that traverses the array of directories and the files contained in them like you described, and then when the first file name match is found, invoke the `pug.compileFile` function (which returns a function that accepts an object for template variables) to return a **render** function (the same render function as `res.render`, you're just creating it yourself instead of relying on Express and its `view engine` settings)

Comment: If you'd like further clarification please let me know, and I'll draft an example in an answer.

Comment: hi @antino , please, draft an example so we all can see it better? ;)